# Starting service from other apk - throws NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: android

i have two projects in Eclipse: service and UI client.

In onCreate in UI client I have:

```
startService(new Intent(this, ExampleService.class));
```

but this fragment:

```
ExampleService.class
```

throws NoClassDefFoundError exception at runtime. I have installed ExampleService.apk, and ExampleUiClient.apk. Project compiles, and everything looks fine. What I am doing wrong?

**Is it possible to start service from other apk?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a broadcast/broadcast receiver

Comment: could you comment please on the pros/cons of `broadcast` vs `intent.setClassName` as in @John's answer? His approach worked for me and seems to be really simple

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov: With Johns's method, you need to know the name of the class. It really depends on your use case I guess.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to use a service from a different package, you can't use the simple invocation in the Android example because your first argument references the context of your current package, which is by definition the wrong place to look.

You have to create the intent and then use setClassName(String, String), where the arguments are the other package and the *full* name of the service. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.Something", "com.example.Something.MyService");
startService(intent);
```

Also note this is a simple case which presumes a default action with no arguments - you also have to make sure that the package containing the service has android:exported="true" set for the service if you don't have any intent-filter declarations, otherwise the call will fail due to a lack of permissions.

Comment: a nitpick: given that the 1st arg is a package name, it should be `com.example.something` - i.e. all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The service needs to be declared in the AndroidManifest.xml of your client.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml from ExampleService.apk: 

<service android:name="com.domain.ExampleService"         android:exported="true"></service>


I added to AndroidManifest.xml from ExampleUiClient.apk
    <service android:name="com.domain.ExampleService" android:exported="true"></service>
 
but it didn't help.

Any other idea? I have similar problem previously with facebook sdk. There was facebook.apk, and I was unable to create instance of Facebook class in my project because of the same problem - it throws NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Is the apk also using the same package? May be try explicit names:
new Intent("com.domain.mypackage", "com.domain.mypackage.MyService");