# Android stand alone and service in different apks

Tags: android, binding, service, apk, android-service

Question fellow programmers. Let's say I have a stand alone application in it's own .apk and I have another .apk which contains a service. How do I start/stop the service and listen to intents from the standalone application? Would service binding work in this case?

I have done application with their own services in the same .apk but unfortunately I have to split them up, each with their own apk.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why this would be any different than what you would do in the intraapp case.  You can just check to see if the intent will succeed [like this.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html)  You will then bind to the service using the package and class name, just as you would in the same app.  Of course, it depends on whether or not you want to use just intents, or whether you want to implement an AIDL interface.  So, in reality, besides checking whether the app is actually installed, there shouldn't be any real change.

You should also note that you should protect the ability to get the intent with a permission, especially if you are doing something privileged (usually you are).  Otherwise your app could be a potential target for confused deputy attacks.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong.In my case I think intents would work. However, since the application and the service are in separate apks they are in different processes. Would this work by simply implementing a messenger within my service?

Comment: I'm confused, intents and messengers are separate things.  Intents are just simple messages between apps / activities, but I'm not sure why you would need a messenger.  If you need a bound service, then you use a messenger, but intents are just messeages you get and have queued up for you you handle in your Service's onStart().

Comment: You are right sorry for the lack of context. I need the messenger in order to bind to the service since they are on separate processes. Is binding from separate apk still possible by using a messenger?

Comment: Yes, it is still possible using the Messenger pattern, there's nothing that much different between intra and inter app services...

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. After reading the documentation and matching it with your answer, you are indeed correct sir. I also saw this solution on so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379354/starting-service-from-other-apk-throws-noclassdeffounderror-exception